# Boost program_options - change output format

Tags: c++, boost

I have tried to use program_options for parsing config file. Some of my inputs are large floating point numbers. For example,

[test_section]

test = 1e23

but using

```
po::options_description desc("");
desc.add_options()("test_section.test",po::value<double(),"Test");
po::variables_map vm;
vm = po::variables_map();

std::ifstream settings_file( input_filename,std::ifstream::in );

po::store( po::parse_config_file( settings_file , desc, true ), vm );
settings_file.close();
po::notify( vm );

double test = vm["test_section.test"].as<double>();
```

yields a bad cast error. How should I solve this problem? Can I define format of floating point numbers somehow?

Comment: The code contains a syntax error. Are you certain that you copy&pasted actual code that compiled and ran and exhibited the problem?